# The Map Object in my Flutter app is giving me an empty function error

Tags: flutter, dart, oop

Here is the code giing me the error and the error is " A function body must be provided.  Try adding a function body." I have tried two ways and still I have the same errors.

Here is the code

```
 Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
return {"uid": uid, "email": email, "name": name,};}
```

I also tried this code too

```
Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
  {"uid": uid, "email": email, "name": name,};
```

Here is the main code

```html
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class UserModel {
  final String uid;
  final String name;
  final String email;

  UserModel({
    required this.uid,
    required this.name,
    required this.email,
  })

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() =>
      {"uid": uid, "email": email, "name": name,};


  static UserModel fromSnap(DocumentSnapshot snap) {
    var snapshot = snap.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

    return UserModel(
        uid: snapshot["uid"],
      name: snapshot["name"],
        email: snapshot["email"],
    );
  }
}
```

What do I do?

Comment: seems ok, can you include the full model class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot a semi-colon `;` after your `UserModel` constructor.

```
class UserModel {
  UserModel({
    required this.uid,
    required this.name,
    required this.email,
  });
  final String uid;
  final String name;
  final String email;

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        'uid': uid,
        'email': email,
        'name': name,
      };

  static UserModel fromSnap(DocumentSnapshot snap) {
    final snapshot = snap.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;
    return UserModel(
      uid: snapshot['uid'] as String,
      name: snapshot['name'] as String,
      email: snapshot['email'] as String,
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Dahal, I saw that and was almost furious at myself. Thank you